# Any jQuery Gantt Chart with Treeview, Zoom and editing features?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, gantt-chart

I have to integrate a `Gantt Chart` like tool in a room booking solution using jQuery. The Gantt should be very interactive one rather than simply displaying data. It should respond to drag & drop, it should have a tree view on the left side to group the tasks, and it should have the zoom feature to zoom in and out of the timeline. I did a lot of research but all those available currently on the web is lacking atleast any one of the mentioned features.

Could anyone tell me if there is anything like this using jQuery?

I know this may sound crazy to have these many features in a single thing. So a subset of the mentioned features would also be very helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I developed this one: http://roberto.open-lab.com/2012/08/24/jquery-gantt-editor/

is a complete editor based on jQuery.

New release available: http://roberto.open-lab.com/2014/05/15/jquery-gantt-editor-collapsible-branches

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this one on http://taitems.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/ - its not 100% perfect yet but for my needs which are basic presentation of time tracking - it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [dhtmlxGantt](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml), it supports all mentioned features:

- interactive Gantt chart - respond to drag-and-drop
- a tree view at the left
- zoom feature (customizable timescale)
- easy integration with jQuery

It's free under GPL.

(Disclaimer: I work for DHTMLX)